# Remove background noise from the shapes I want to see

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract some nematodes from an image, but there is background noise. The noise is usually round while the animals are elongated.

My idea is: for each blob I take its area and its perimeter and then make a relation between both parameters as follows: area/perimeter. If the number is high it means that the area is large while if it is the other way around the perimeter is large with respect to the area.
I have done this code, but it does not work:

[image: Proba]

[image: Proba1]

[image: Proba2]

```
    im = cv2.imread("blablabla")
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    areas = []
    perim = []
    min = 0.1
    result = np.zeros_like(im).astype(np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        moments = cv2.moments(contours[i])
        a = moments["m00"]
        areas.append(a)
        p = len(contours[i])
        perim.append(p)
        a_p = p/a
        if a_p >= min:
            result[im == i] = 255
    plt.imshow(result)
    plt.show()
```

The result is this image:

[image: Result]

Comment: input data is important. [mre] please.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the 1st image is what I call blablabla in the code. I don't know if I have to upload something else.

Comment: that is a screenshot of a plot of a picture... that was already processed. we need the original, unfiltered, untouched, source, if you expect decent recommendations. please review [mre].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry for the inconvenience, I have already edited the initial image. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Can't you just filter on area. Your noise blobs are small in area compared to the objects you have in that image.

Comment: @fmw42 This is only one of many images I have to analyze. Sometimes blobs are bigger and, for example, in this image there are some very small nematodes that would dissapear (because they're smaller than the noise). That's why I want to get the perimeter and area.

Comment: Suggest you post a representative sample of images.

Comment: @fmw42 Done! Thanks for the advice. I've updated it and this are all the images I have.

Comment: all the pictures I see are binarized already. that is filtering. _source_ data please. there might be ways to deal with this issue before it happens (before the binarization).

Comment: I don't see how `result[im == i] = 255` works. Your image is im but i is an index on the contours. Why would the image be equal to the index? Does not make sense to me. Can you explain. Perhaps I misunderstand.